# CFFI Python best (more pythonic) practices

Tags: python, c, pypy, cffi

I seek for some best practices that may help to make Pythonic (and object-oriented) code from cffi code, or Python packages that can make/generate Pythonic code from cffi code.

For example, I want to get some `struct` of one `char*` and two `float*` and two `int*` so I could edit struct's fields without needing to convert Python variable to good-for-cffi variable (like `ffi.new("int*", 42)`) and I want that Pythonic struct to be easily passable through CFFI.

If there is any package, please share usage examples for `struct` case.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to put pointers in your struct? That makes things complicated since you have to manage the lifetime of the objects those pointers reference. There is no "nice" way to do this in CFFI because there is no "nice" way to do this in C.

Comment: This struct is not mine struct, it's struct of other library, so I don't want to change it.